# Open VPN Issue, servers can not route properly

Tags: ubuntu, routing, openvpn

I need some help on this issue. Basically I have a server which I have openvpn installed on. It is working fine and I am able to ping the server which I am connected to and can ping back. What I am trying to do is be able to access other servers which are connected to it on their own private network.

Currently my VPN is set up with 10.8.0.0/24 and my servers are set up with 10.0.0.0/24. The computer connected can ping both 10.8.0.1 (the vpn server) and 10.0.0.1 (the private ip of the server where the VPN is installed), but can not ping 10.0.0.2. When I do a tcpdump I can see that the request is getting to the 10.0.0.2 server, but it does not know what to do with the request after that as it can not find the original 10.8.0.10 (computer connected to vpn as client), as it is an ip on the vpn on a different server. Is there a way to tell the 10.0.0.0/24 where to send the traffic? If so, how. I have tried a bunch of different things from modifying iptables and routes, but nothing seems to work.

Here is the tcp request from the 10.0.0.2 server which was sent from my 10.8.0.10 client:

```
IP 10.8.0.10 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 1
IP 10.0.0.2 > 10.8.0.10: ICMP echo reply, id 1
IP 10.8.0.10 > 10.0.0.2: ICMP net 10.8.0.10 unreachable - unknown
```

For notes:

> Yes IP Forwarding is enabled on all servers.
>
> There is no DHCP server for the 10.0.0.0/24 servers as they are all static

Let me know if you need anything else.

**Edit**

So as someone suggested I should give a bit more information so I will.

All of the servers involved are either running Server Ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04, and have all of their software up to date. The 10.0.0.2 server has the following set as one of the routes which I figured was going to work, but when I try to ping 10.8.0.1 I get errors. The servers are configured in a network by my host so I don't have total control over that.

Routing table for 10.0.0.2 with servers ip blanked out

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         -.-.-.-         0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun1
10.8.0.0        10.0.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun1

PING 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unknown
From 10.8.0.1 icmp_seq=2 Destination Net Unknown
```

Routing Table for 10.0.0.1 with my servers ip blanked out

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         -.-.-.-         0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 tun1
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to enable IP forwarding on all servers. It's only needed on the server which is doing routing between multiple networks, aka your OpenVPN server.
- It seems that the machine running on 10.0.0.2 has no idea how to route back the traffic originating in your 10.8.0.0/24. You need to set correct routes: Either directly on this host, or, maybe more clever if there are more machines involved, on the default gateway, if this exists. [This step tells your device / devices, how to reach 10.8.0.0/24.] How to do this, depends on your OS and the involved devices. (Maybe it would be good to share some more details.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have updated the question above. Hopefully that provides more information. You are right though, that is what I am thinking is the problem but not totally sure how to fix it.

Comment: Do you control 10.0.0.1? If so: Could you show the routing table as well?

Comment: Updated with 10.0.0.1 routing table.

Comment: Any idea why there are two `tun` devices? And: Could you show `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` on 10.0.0.1? What do the * mean in the second routing table?

Comment: One tunnel device is my openvpn connection and the other is created by the private network between my servers. ip_forward is set to 1 and I can see the ping request on the 10.0.0.2 server, it just dies there and doesn't know where to send the return. No idea what the * means, my guess would be that it is any ip.

Comment: So your network looks roughly like: Client <- OpenVPN 1 -> 10.0.0.1 <- OpenVPN 2 -> 10.0.0.2?

Comment: Yea, except between the 10.0.0.0/24 servers are a mesh network (I have more, up to 10.0.0.18, my guess by using Tinc or something similar to that) and they can all independently communicate with each other, but no one else can get into them.

Comment: I see. I think the problem is the last line of the routing table of 10.0.0.1. As I read this (but I could be wrong as well) there is no address set as a gateway for 10.8.0.2. I guess, if you fix this, the problem will be solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30951/discussion-between-burgoyn1-and-gf).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> When I do a tcpdump I can see that the request is getting to the 10.0.0.2 server, but it does not know what to do with the request after that as it can not find the original 10.8.0.10
> ```

You set a route on the 10.0.0.0/24 gateway. Eg if your router is the gw on 10.0.0.0/24. You set a static route to 10.8.0.0/24 via your VPN host IP (10.0.0.0/24 range). When your server 10.0.0.2 see the packet incoming but he doesn't know where to send it so he will query the gateway. The gateway then needs to know the route to send the packet back.

Comment: Right, except I don't have control over the 10.0.0.0/24 gateway, or at least I don't think I have control over it as it is created by my host. I was wondering if there is a way to do it on a server by server level instead of by gateway.

Comment: @burgoyn1 Just as a test, try setting the route manually on that one server 10.0.0.2. Just to make sure it is a routing issue. AFAIK I don't think you can. But maybe the others will have a solution.

Comment: I did, which is what the 10.8.0.0 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0 is, unless I am misunderstanding what you are saying. By doing that I went from getting nothing to getting the Destination Net Unknown error, which is where I am getting stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a very long time I finally figured out what was wrong. Turns out, my vpn configuration was correct the entire time. lbanz was partially right about the gateway not knowing where to go. What was happening is the 10.8.0.0/24 requests were going into the secondary network and getting lost, as it was a 10.0.0.0/24 network, which did not know how to handle it.

What I had to do was contact my host and ask them to assign the ip range of 10.8.0.0/24 to my 10.0.0.1 server, and now everything works like a charm. Thanks everyone for the input, really helped me narrow down the issue.